Telegram method/messages.requestWebView in telegram not return chat_instance
I use this code to open Mini Apps in telegram(get data authen)
var webViewResult = await client.Messages_RequestWebView(
    bot,
    bot.User,
    "android", 
    null,
    "https://t.me/xxxx_bot", 
    null, 
    "P81AFIL", 
    client.User,
    false);

In this document https://core.telegram.org/bots/webapps there is a description when using Direct Link Mini App
In this mode, Mini Apps can use the chat_type and chat_instance parameters to keep track of the current chat context. This introduces support for concurrent and shared usage by multiple chat members – to create live whiteboards, group orders, multiplayer games and similar apps.
But when calling client.Messages_RequestWebView the response does not contain chat_type and chat_instance parameters.
https://t.me/taptether_bot#tgWebAppData=query_id%3DAxxxxfhgYZ6nA%26user%3D%257B%2522id%2522%253A6853373296%252C%2522first_name%2522%253A%2522rom%2522%252C%2 522last_name%2522%253A%2522% 2522%252C%2522username%2522%253A%2522xxxxx%2522%252C%2522language_code%2522%253A%2522en%2522%252C%2522allows_write_to_pm%2522%253Atrue%257D%26auth_date%3D172 1580273%26hash%3Dxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx&tgWebAppVersion=7.6&tgWebAppPlatform=android

Get chat_type and chat_instance in response data
